# SQL query handling three tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compile the data for reporting purpose, using php communicating with postgres,
I have three tables

**product_status**:

```
status_code | value
------------|------
    1       |  a
    2       |  b
```

**product_child**:

```
code| ID | status_code
----|----|------------
 X  |  1 |   1
 X  |  2 |   1
 X  |  3 |   2
 Y  |  1 |   2
 Y  |  2 |   2
 Z  |  1 |   1
```

**product_master**:

```
code|description(and some other columns not relevent)
 X  |    la
 Y  |    alb
 Z  |    lab
```

In the end I want basically a table like this which i'll display

```
    | total child | status a | status b
bla |    3        |  2       |   1
alb |    2        |  0       |   2
lab |    1        |  1       |   0
```

I have tried

```
SELECT s.value, count(s.value) 
FROM product_child p, product_status s 
WHERE
    p.product_status = s.status_code 
    and p.product_code = get_product_code('Sofa (1-seater) J805') 
group by 
    s.value
```

it gives we grouping for particular code but I want this flipped and appended in front of distinct product_codes

Comment: it gives we grouping for perticular code but i want this flipped and appended in front of distinct product_codes
`SELECT s.value,count(s.value)
FROM product_child p, product_status s
where p.product_status = s.status_code
and p.product_code = get_product_code('Sofa (1-seater) J805')
group by s.value`

Comment: what is `get_product_code('Sofa (1-seater) J805')`? Is it a function?

Comment: @bluefeet yup self defined function

Comment: See (and follow!): [Stop using the old-style JOIN syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like this?

```
select  pm.description,
        count(pc.code) total,
        count(case when ps.value = 'A' then ps.value else null end) statusA,
        count(case when ps.value = 'B' then ps.value else null end) statusB
from    product_master pm join product_child pc on pm.code = pc.code
        join product_status ps on pm.status_code = ps.status_code
group by pm.description
```

Comment: but what if i dont know the cases before hand, i am just thinking a scalable solution

Comment: then I think you'll need to use the postgres `crosstab` function (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html)

Comment: that seems promising paul, i think i can do that, Thanks mate